# I cannot switch to Nvidia Graphic Card on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I am using a Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 dual boot system.

Nvidia card: GTX-1060MQ.

Driver version: x86_64-430.14 (installed by running the `.run` file download from nvidia.com).

I have installed the newest nvidia driver, and the "nvidia-smi" command works well.

[image: nvidia-smi]

But the "About this computer" page shows a Intel graphic card rather than a Nvidia card.

[image: About this Computer]

I cannot open the "Nvidia X Server Settings" software. And the "nvidia-settings" command show errors like below:

```
ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system
```

How can I switch to the Nvidia card? Thank you very much!

Comment: Which Nvidia card? Which driver version and how did you installed it?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Nvidia card: GTX-1060MQ, driver version: x86_64-430.14, installed by running the ".run" file.

Comment: 1. Please [edit] the question to add those details. 2. Do NOT install from Nvidia binaries. If the required driver version isn't available in the Ubuntu repositories then add the graphics drivers PPA first. Then you can install at Software & Updates > Additional Drivers (maybe in 16.04 it's "Software Properties", if I'm remembering correctly, it was a long time ago). Also for new hardware prefer newer releases, like the 18.04 LTS or even newer like the current 19.04 that can be updated later to 19.10 and then again to a LTS next year with 20.04.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I uninstalled the driver installed using `.run` file. And then installed the newest driver version `430.14` using `PPA`, but a new error occurred when I reboot the computer: `The system is running in low-graphics mode`, I can not enter the system. If I use `sudo prime-select intel`, I can start the system. Why this happed and can I fix it? Thank you very much!

Comment: First, disable secure boot in UEFI settings as it prevents unsigned drivers from loading, reason why Intel works (open-source drivers) and Nvidia don't. If any error after this reinstall the Nvidia drivers.